# Using CFFI in Common Lisp, calling functions returning pointers

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, cffi

I am using SBCL, and trying to use CFFI. I started following the manual [here](https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/Tutorial_002dInitializing.html#Tutorial_002dInitializing) but I kept getting that the function `curl_easy_init` is undefined, so I decided to try a simpler case.

Some functions work as expected, while others seem to be not defined. This is explained below:

Here is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* "Works" except output doesn't appear. Not important for now */
void hello()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
}

/* Works as expected */
float add(float x1, float x2)
{
  return x1 + x2;
}

/* appears to not be defined in SBCL*/
void* init_this()
{
  return malloc(10);
}

/* Appears to not be defined in SBCL*/
void clean_this(void* ptr)
{
  free(ptr);
}
```

This C file is compiled as:

```
gcc -shared -o cffi_test.so -fPIC cffi_test.c
```

My Common Lisp code:

```
(quicklisp:quickload "cffi")

(defpackage :my-cffi
  (:use :common-lisp :cffi))

(in-package :my-cffi)
(export '(hello add init_this clean_this))


(define-foreign-library cffi_test
  (t (:default "~/Work/clisp/cffi_test")))

(use-foreign-library cffi_test)

(defcfun "hello" :void)
(defcfun "add" :float (x1 :float ) (x2 :float))
(defcfun "init_this" :pointer)
(defcfun "clean_this" :void (handle :pointer))
```

What I get as I expect:

```
* (my-cffi:add 3.0 4.0)

7.0
```

**What appears to be a problem:**

```
(my-cffi:init_this)
```

Generates the error:

```
The function MY-CFFI:INIT_THIS is undefined.
   [Condition of type UNDEFINED-FUNCTION]

...

Backtrace:
  0: (SB-IMPL::RETRY-%COERCE-NAME-TO-FUN MY-CFFI:INIT_THIS NIL)
      Locals:
        SB-IMPL::NAME = MY-CFFI:INIT_THIS
        SB-IMPL::STRICTLY-FUNCTIONP = NIL
```

I get same error for `clean_this` , and in the link above, following the manual, for `curl_easy_init` which inspired this experiment.

Comment: CFFI translates underscores to dashes in foreign names.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Do you want to post that in the answer section so I can accept it and close this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A foreign name given as a string to `CFFI:DEFCFUN` will be converted into a lispier name using the generic function [`CFFI:TRANSLATE-NAME-FROM-FOREIGN`](https://common-lisp.net/project/cffi/manual/html_node/translate_002dname_002dfrom_002dforeign.html#translate_002dname_002dfrom_002dforeign). The default behavior is to change underscores to hyphens:

```
CL-USER> (cffi:translate-name-from-foreign "mylib_fun_name" *package*)
MYLIB-FUN-NAME
```

You can also give a lisp name explicitly in the function definition:

```
(defcfun ("mylib_fun_name" fun-name) ...)
```